# Ошибка в libclamav

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Прошу помощи с компиляцией [clamav](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/blob/master/examples/ex1.c)

Подключил библиотеки, скомпилировал. После запуска подключает базу, выводит кол-во сигнатур.
Дальше крашится.

В дебагере нашел нужную строку:

```
if ((ret = cl_scandesc(fd, &virname, &size, engine, CL_SCAN_STDOPT)) == CL_VIRUS) { //!!!!!
    printf("Virus detected: %s\n", virname);
}
```

Ошибка:

> Библиотека времени выполнения Microsoft Visual Studio C обнаружила неустранимую ошибку в file.exe

Компилятор - msvc++ 2017
Пробовал и x86, и x64 - результат тот же.
Как исправить эту ошибку? Спасибо.

Comment: Какие значения у аргументов при вызове?

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена.

Comment: если проблема не в банальной опечатке, то можете написать ответ. Кто-то скажет вам спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используя clamav api, можно сканировать буфер, дескриптор или файл:

```
int cl_scanbuff(const char *buffer, unsigned int length,
const char **virname, const struct cl_node *root);

int cl_scandesc(int desc, const char **virname, unsigned
long int *scanned, const struct cl_node *root, const
struct cl_limits *limits, int options);

int cl_scanfile(const char *filename, const char **virname,
unsigned long int *scanned, const struct cl_node *root,
const struct cl_limits *limits, int options);
```

Заставить работать пример со сканированием дескриптора у меня так и не получилось (автор использовал gcc, я - msvc), поэтому я просто использовал функцию сканирования файла cl_scanfile. Заработало с первого раза.